# How do I call a function inside a c++ class without creating a new object from python with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a class in c++ that has a setter that I want to be able to call from python using pybind11. I do not want to turn the entire class into a module that can be called in python because I cannot reinitiate the c++ class in python. I would like to basically pass a pointer to that function to python.

This is what I have right now:

```
class PybindStrategy {

~PybindStrategy();

public: 

/**
 * This event triggers whenever trade message arrives from a market data source.
 */ 
virtual void trade();
}
```

I would like to call trade in python

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(PybindStrat, m) {
   m.doc() = "starts a trade"; 
   m.def("trade", &PybindStrategy::trade);
}
```

This however does not work

Comment: That method is not static, and therefore you need to first instantiate the class and then you can call its methods (either from C++ or python). You could export the class to python without exporting its constructor, so that you cannot initialise it from python.